# Test Train Dataframe for multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, data-science

I have a csv file

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume,Cash EPS,Book Value,Div/share,Net profit/share,NPM,ROE,ROCE,ROA,DEBT/EQ,ATR,CR
2004-04-26,82.924217,82.924217,82.924217,82.924217,60.026066,0,221.24,488.21,129.5,186.6,26.11,38.22,38.22,24.2,0,92.67,1.65
2004-04-27,82.778122,82.778122,79.765625,80.24453,58.086323,28616000,221.24,488.21,129.5,186.6,26.11,38.22,38.22,24.2,0,92.67,1.65
```

Giving only 2 rows for easy calculations. I have created a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

dataframe1 = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df = dataframe1.dropna()
scaler=MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
df1=scaler.fit_transform(np.array(df1).reshape(-1,1))
min_max_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
df[["Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Adj Close", "Volume", "Book Value", "Div/share", "Net profit/share", "NPM", "ROE", "ROCE", "ROA", "DEBT/EQ", "ATR", "CR"]] = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(df[["Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Adj Close", "Volume", "Book Value", "Div/share", "Net profit/share", "NPM", "ROE", "ROCE", "ROA", "DEBT/EQ", "ATR", "CR"]])
```

To train a dataset, I need date as well as prediction i.e. close column.
But, Close column value depends on multiple columns (i.e. all columns present in this csv)

How can I train the data for date and close columns but based on all other columns so that prediction for future close is possible?

Comment: Are you looking for a machine learning algorithm recommendation?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do.  My best guess is that you are trying to predict close for date T+1 based on the existing columns?  Are you asking how to set this up, or how to make the prediction?

Comment: @TroyD To train data, we need 2 columns (date and close) but these values are based on other factors (other all mentioned columns). How can we train the data for close using other columns too for dates?

Comment: @vcucu: main problem is training based on multiple columns

Comment: It does not seem to me that adding multiple input variables should be a problem, but it depends on what algorithm you wish to use for the prediction - there are many different regression/time-series approaches you may want to apply. Most common ones allow adding multiple numeric columns to train on.

Comment: @vcucu : can you please show an example of any machine learning algorithm which uses a time-series approach for adding "multiple columns" to train the data?

Comment: If you're looking for an example of a ML model that makes time series predictions, Long-Short Term Memory models may be what you're looking for: https://machinelearningmastery.com/gentle-introduction-long-short-term-memory-networks-experts/

Comment: From simple linear regression all the way to LSTM neural nets as linked by @TroyD. Or ARIMA/SARIMAX from statsmodels also allow for exogenous variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question, you're looking for a multi-variate time-series model.  In other words, it take multiple variable inputs for each time step in order to make forward looking predictions.  Here's a link to some examples:

https://www.relataly.com/stock-market-prediction-with-multivariate-time-series-in-python/1815/

Also, I'd suggest looking into the Kaggle stock market prediction competition, there's hundreds of examples of how people approach this problem.

https://www.kaggle.com/c/two-sigma-financial-news